# Wordpress questionnaire plugin that allows for limited time to submit questionnaire

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

Hi I have a someone wanting to post videos on their website and then having a questionnaire that their clients must answer after watching the video. The tricky part is that they want the questionnaire answered within a limited number of days after watching the video. Looking for a plugin / solution

Comment: You could set a cookie on the users machine for 30 days (for example), then check for the cookie before serving the questionnaire. You would need to check the cookie doesn't exist before setting it otherwise the 30 days would reset every time they viewed the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above. I would do this via cookies (example is for 30 days). This should run in your functions.php file:

```
function questionnaire() {

    //if you are on the video page and there is no cookie, then set it

    if(is_page('videopage') && !isset($_COOKIE["videoView"])) {
        setcookie("videoView", "Viewed the video", time()+30*24*60*60); 

    // else if you're on the questionnaire page and there's no cookie, then redirect the user

     } elseif (is_page('questionnairepage') && !isset($_COOKIE["videoView"]) {
         wp_redirect( 'videopage' );
         exit;
     }  
}

add_action( 'init', 'questionnaire' );
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go